# What's my Ubuntu Server administrator password?

Tags: ubuntu, password

I just installed Ubuntu Server here, which went fine. However, not sure what's going on here now.

I installed gnome using `sudo aptitude install --without-recommends ubuntu-desktop`, which worked great. But, I'm not able to use the Synaptic Package Manager!

When using the Login Screen thing I can click unlock and it asks for authorization. I enter the password I gave during install, and it works fine. But when SPM asks for my password, it doesn't accept it! What's going on? My user password is the only one I have been asked to create. I can use `sudo` fine in the terminal. Why does SPM block me here?

Comment: im not a ubuntu person myself, but try setting a root password with `sudo passwd root` (then give your normal password for the sudo and then a root password you want)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to set password for root, you should type command in console:

**$ sudo su**

(type your's user password)

# **passwd**

Now you can set or change password for root ;-)

Comment: A bit curious though... why wasn't this an issue with the desktop version?